# Find the smallest singular value of a perturbed matrix

Tags: matrices, perturbation-theory

Consider a perturbed matrix $\widetilde{H}=H+\delta H$ such that $\|\delta H\|_\text{F}\leq \varepsilon$,

where $\widetilde{H}$ and $\varepsilon$ are known.

I am wondering how I can find the smallest singular value $\sigma_{\text{min}}$ of $H$?  Are there any bounds for $\sigma_{\text{min}}$? I do appreciate your insights.

This is what I have done so far:

To find $\sigma_{\text{min}}$, I did a perturbation analysis of the singular value problem $H= U \Sigma V^T$, i.e.,

$$\Sigma + \delta\Sigma = U^T(H+\delta H)V.$$

Since $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal or unitary, they preserve norms.  Accordingly,

$$\|\delta\Sigma\|_\text{F} = \|\delta H\|_\text{F}.$$

Also, from Mirsky's theorem, the inequality

$$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (\tilde{\sigma_i}-\sigma_i)^2} \leq \|\delta H\|_\text{F}$$

holds, where $\tilde{\sigma_i}$ is the approximate of $\sigma_i$ due to the perturbation matrix $\delta H$. I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: $H = \frac{1}{1+\delta}\widetilde{H}$ and $\|A^{-1}\|_2=\frac{1}{\sigma_\text{min}}$.  These are some ideas you might play around with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Weyl's inequality
$$
|\sigma_{\min}(\widetilde H)-\sigma_{\min}(H)| \leq \|\widetilde H-H\|_2 \leq \|\delta H\|_2 \leq \|\delta H\|_F \leq \varepsilon.
$$